# What algorithm does Windows use to render various style and size of the same font?

Tags: windows

When I set a block of text to be bold or italic and change its size , what Windows does  under the hood ? Is  the new text image just an affine transformation of the original one ?

Comment: Previously GDI/+ and currently DirectWrite I suppose: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface

Comment: This question is more appropriate to superuser.com.  However, it does have a definite answer.

Comment: A quick search of superuser didn't turn up any obvious dupes there.

Answer (score 2):

Limiting the discussion to outline fonts such as Type 1 and TrueType/OpenType, the answer is that it depends on the font.

Fonts defined as vector outlines can be scaled.  Usually they have additional information called 'hints' that direct the renderer to make certain adjustments such as ensuring that various lines are the same width or that certain parts are not rendered above or below baselines below a given size.  This is important for rendering the font at low resolutions.

Many fonts have italic designs, which are separate from the upright.  In this case the system will use the italic font.  If no italic is available it may synthesize an oblique font by applying a shear transform to the upright.

Some fonts have different designs for rendering at higher or lower resolutions.  The Original Adope Type-1 rendition of Optima is an example of a font that uses this technique.

Some fonts can have parameters applied to their shape - Adobe Multiple Master fonts are an example of this technique.  Font outlines are defined in terms of control points of spline curves.  On multiple master fonts the control points for the splines are defined as tracks rather than points.  The additional parameter defines how far along the tracks the control points move.  This allows (for example) the boldness level or obliquing of a font to be controlled by tweaking the variables.  The movement of the control points can compensate for artefacts of the adjustment, for example making sure the width of uprights remains constant during shearing.

**References**

- [This](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/T1_SPEC.PDF) is the specification for the Adobe Type-1 font format.
- [Wikipedia entry on multiple master fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts)
- [Wikipedia entry on the OpenType font format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType)
- [Paper on font rendering](https://freddie.witherden.org/pages/font-rasterisation/)